# Linux friendly server oriented motherboard for Intel i7 11700

Tags: motherboard, linux, server, intel

Any recommendation for an ATX motherboard for Intel i7 11700 that would run well under Linux (Ubuntu)?

I'm having a hard time to find a review of SOHO server oriented mobos. Mostly people review the gaming ones. I'm concerned with the available PCI extention slots. I guess I'd need to install a SATA extension board for extra RAID HDDs as I want to have 8 SATA drives altogether. It would also be nice to have most modern USB standards onboard for connecting the external devices. I'll be using the integrated GPU at first.

Anyone had good experience with your build for something not just gaming oriented, so you could share the parts list?

Comment: For PCIe stuff, thats limited by your cpu, that one only has 20 lanes. As for SATA, Z590 can only have up to 6 ports. As for USB, Z590 is ok, with maximum 10 USB3.0 ports. I have not looked into other chipsets because Z590 is highest end on that cpu

Comment: thanks for clarification @Irsu85. I'm thinking about MSI MPG Z590 Gaming Carbon WIFI, So.1200, ATX (7D06-001R), any comment on that specific mobo?

Comment: Not enough SATA ports, but thats a chipset limitation and you still got very limited PCIe expansion compared to HEDT or server stuff like Threadripper or Epyc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Threadripper would be better for server stuff when you need a lot of expantion. The ASUS Zenith II Extreme checks all of the boxes, but you need at least a 24core cpu with it (threadripper 3960X) and its a bit expensive (and eATX). Why the intel 11700 is not possible, please see my comment on the question. All motherboards that I know of run well with Linux so don't worry about that  please. It has 10gbit lan so thats good for server stuff

Comment: Thanks for the perspecitve. This should clearly go to the comment though, as I have asked specifically about Intel (due to the integrated GPU that I need for video transcoding)

Answer (score 0):

your *run well* under *linux* is non specific, but assuming I think I know what u mean, probably `supermicro` workstation motherboards since you mentioned `SOHO`.  Consumer boards, such as asrock or msi, I've had issues with at home running linux (rhel/centos, whether ubuntu would have I don't know) regarding graphics.  Normally nouveau in linux should make any cpu integrated graphics work regardless of mobo choice.

https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboards/matrix

Boards from supermicro, dell, hp would be I think what you are looking for for a SOHO linux setup.

the supermicro X12SCA-5F supports pcie 4.0 and has m.2 capability, allows for 128gb ram, and so on... https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X12SCA-5F

Comment: I run Linux on an I5 7400 with an ASUS board now, no issues at the moment, it actually fixed most issues I had with my last server (Ubuntu Server 20.04)